# How to link Calendar.get_date() with a StringVar() in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkcalendar

I've been working on a GUI for a sort of "Rota manager" app that has a calendar object in the main window to allow the user to select a specific date on it and record beginning and end of his/her working shift.
In the main window I would like to have a tk.Label that display the date selected on the calendar and change every time the user clicks on a different day.
I found a lot of question related to something similar but I can't figure it how to make the label update itself after a click.
So far I could only display the first selection of the date (today's date by default).
Here the part of the code:

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import StringVar
    from tkcalendar import Calendar

    class MainWindow:
        def __init__(self, master):
            self.master = master
            master.title("Rota Manager")
            master.geometry("400x550")
            master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            master.resizable(False, False)
            self.cal = Calendar(self.master, font="Arial 14", selectmode='day', date_pattern='dd/mm/yy')
            self.cal.grid(sticky='nsew', pady=10, padx=5)
            self.v = StringVar()
            self.dynamic_label = tk.Label(self.master, textvariable=self.v, font=('Arial', 10))
            self.dynamic_label.grid(row=5, sticky='n')
            self.v.set(f"Date selected: {self.cal.get_date()}")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        root = tk.Tk()
        app = MainWindow(root)
        root.mainloop()
```

This is just the portion of the code with the task I'm asking about.
As usual, thanks a lot to whoever can help.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use Calendar's `textvariable` option to keep track of the selected day. So just connect both the label and the calendar to the same `StringVar`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import StringVar
from tkcalendar import Calendar

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Rota Manager")
        master.geometry("400x550")
        master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        master.resizable(False, False)
        self.v = StringVar(self.master, Calendar.date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%y"))
        self.cal = Calendar(self.master, font="Arial 14", selectmode='day', 
                            date_pattern='dd/mm/yy', textvariable=self.v)
        self.cal.grid(sticky='nsew', pady=10, padx=5)

        label_frame = tk.Frame(self.master) # put static label and dynamic label in single frame
        tk.Label(label_frame, text="Date selected: ", 
                 font=('Arial', 10)).pack(side="left")  # static_label
        self.dynamic_label = tk.Label(label_frame, 
                                      textvariable=self.v, font=('Arial', 10))
        self.dynamic_label.pack(side="left")
        label_frame.grid(row=5, sticky='n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, I noticed that adding to my code the textvariable parameter to the calendar object make it working already. I guess that putting the two label in the same frame is to be able to have the string "date selected" always on. the only issue that I have now is that later on in the script when the user submit the data, the value of StringVar will be changed to another string saying "Data written on file" and that generates an error because obviusly that can't be taken as a date by the Calendar object.

Comment: @Py_Rog You can either use to use Lafexlos' solution or, in the submit function, you change the textvariable of the calendar to a new StringVar so that there is no issue with the value.

Comment: make sense. Thanks a lot for the answer and the tips, mate!! Cheers